# $W$ vs $Z$ Boson Interaction

Tags: particle-physics, standard-model, electroweak

My apologies for the simplicity of this question, but I am learning how to analyze basic particle interactions.

[image]

My rationale is the following: The output and the input are both leptons, which means the exchange particle needs to interact with all leptons. Of which, the W and Z bosons would work as a possible exchange particle. However, how do I differentiate between if this is a W and Z boson in this scenario? At least from simple analysis, they would both work.

Any guidance is appreciated.

Comment: Consider charge conservation at each of the vertices.

Comment: consider also that     the Z boson  is neutral

Comment: Btw the photon also interacts with charged leptons though it's not the boson in this instance.